# Resolving "this operation requires IIS integration pipeline mode" in ASP.net MVC2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, download, iis-7.5, notimplementedexception

I'm developing an ASP.net MVC2 application, and implement an export to .csv controller action, but when I add the headers to force the download, The following appears in the debugger:

> "this operation requires IIS integration pipeline mode"

I have searched on numerouse sites with Google, but have yet to resolve this. I am using:

- IIS 7.5
- Windows 7 Ultimate and
- .Net Framework 4.0,

The application pools for ASP.net are configured in integrated pipeline mode, as I don't understand the problem.

Can the community assist me solving this and explaining the error to me?

Answer (score 40):

http://devproj20.blogspot.com/2008/02/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated.html

"You can work around this problem by adding your header this way instead:"

`Response.AddHeader("myHeader", "someValue");`

Comment: @TheMuffinMan According to the [reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,3ba8b457eb5f1b0f,references) it calls `AppendHeader`.  This checks the workerrequest and probably branches off depending on which header-adding is applicable for the hosting environment.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project Project properties (right click on project) and go to web tab on left side and check the property use Local IIS Web Server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM5rv.png)